# Проверка наличия динамически созданного обьекта

Tags: c#

Обьект label создается в коде!
Как проверить создан ли обьект или нет при дальнейшем обращении к нему

Comment: а можете показать как именно он создаётся в коде?

Comment: Если вы используете динамические имена для элемента Label, то вам нужно взять список всех элементов этого типа из формы и проверить его наличие, например по тэгу. Если вы конечно как-то маркировали создаваемые элементы для дальнейшей их идентификации.

Comment: ну так добавьте к тексту своего вопроса фрагмент кода с созданием объекта (=__=) может вы пытаетесь использовать верно созданный объект из другой области видимости, где он уже недоступен...

Answer (score 2):

```
if(label != null)
{
    // Do something
}
```